# is there kinect calibration package in ROS

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, is there any packages about kinect calibration ? I want to the use the ROS for my kinect calibration, we can provide some useful information on it? how to deal with it? thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49451/is-there--kinect-calibration-package-in-ros/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes there is : [camera calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration) package.

[EDIT] By the way, it permits to calibrate RGB camera, IR camera. And one camera reguarding the other one. But not the depth.

So if you use multiple kinect, the depth may be a bit shifted from one to the other one.

Ps : Please, in next post, don't forget to precise :

- which version of ROS you use
- what System you are running it on (ex Ubuntu 10.04)

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-12-02**:
thanks a lot , and my ROS:electric  ,my OS:ubuntu 11.10

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2012-12-03**:
Don't forget to put my answer as correct if you think it closes the subject :-)